# Are there RPMs for GlassFish v3?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, glassfish

It seems that the [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/) project itself does not provide RPM packages, and neither does JPackage (http://jpackage.org/). Is someone else providing ready-built RPM packages for RHEL/CentOS?

On a related note: why are RPM packages so conspicuously missing for GlassFish v3? Don't people install it using packaging systems?

Answer (score 0):

Good question !

I've found one, but it doesn't respect in anyway standard package guidelines. It's more a standard installation put in a RPM...

so here it is:
http://blog.screv.com/?p=143

Comment: URL invalid....,